# How to reorder array of dates?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have this array of dates and trying to reorder the array based on the dates but i don't want to use foreach and loop over the array please any help on this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15/09/2016 00:00
    [1] => 02/09/2016 00:00
    [2] => 01/09/2016 00:00
    [3] => 29/09/2016 00:00
)
```

Comment: @paul Crovella kindly answer this question...

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).  It gives a few different ways to sort arrays